# Java Arrays print

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to type an Array but I get  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`

I googled it and I know everything about this exception but I can't do anything to solve this stupid problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] matrix = new int[3][5];

    for (int i =0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int ii=0; ii<matrix[i].length; i++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][ii]);
        }
        System.out.println(" \n");      
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got a typo:

```
for (int ii=0; ii<matrix[i].length  ;i++)
```

should be

```
for (int ii=0; ii<matrix[i].length  ;ii++)
```

Comment: I feel so stupid , 
thank u very much for answering . I won't use similar letters again.. I spent two hours just looking for an answer . 
Thank you

Comment: @AhmadMorad You're welcome.

Comment: @AhmadMorad, you can use `i`, `j`, `k` as variable names, so that you can differentiate among them.